# Request' object has no attribute 'body - Flask

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm getting three different results which is in json format and want to reflect the result on API. I'm using Flask to show the post request. This should be done by payloads. So, these three json have three different Urls. Earlier I was using hard coded paths to getting the results. Now, new instruction is, dynamically I've to get the paths of all the required data and show the results.

Below code I'm using to show the post request and the main_func() from where I'm getting data. Whenever I'm hitting the code it is showing error - "Request' object has no attribute 'body". I'm bit confused here, to get the result as dynamically.

```
@app.route('/result_spec', methods=['POST'])
def get_result_spec():
    try:
        payload = get_params_api(request)

        result_spec, _, _ = main_func(request = payload)

        return jsonify({"result_spec": result_spec})

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify({"error": str(e)}), 500
```

```
def get_params_api(request):
        # if request and hasattr(request, 'body'):
        if request is not None:  
            json_body = json.loads(request.body)

        # if json_body is not None:
            ads_path = json_body["csv_path"]
            json_path = json_body["spec_path"]
            input_path = json_body["input_path"]

            variable = json_body["variable"]
            files_ = json_body["files_"]
            variable_name1 = json_body["variable_name1"]
            t_and_v = json_body["t_and_v"]

        else:
            csv_path = r"file.csv"
            input_path = r"split_folder"
            json_path = r"sample_transformation.json"

            variable, files_, variable_name1, t_and_v = get_params()

        payload = {
            "csv_path": csv_path,
            "json_path": json_path,
            "input_path": input_path,
            "dependent_variable": dependent_variable,
            "files_geo": files_geo,
            "variable_name": variable_name,
            "trans_and_values": trans_and_values
        }

        return payload
```

```
def main_func(params):

    csv_path = params["csv_path"]
    json_path = params["json_path"]
    input_path = params["input_path"]
    variable = params["variable"]
    files_ = params["files_"]
    variable_name1 = params["variable_name1"]
    t_and_v = params["t_and_v"]
    
    # store_path_list = get_s3_directory_tree(input_path)
    spath_list = get_s3_directory_tree(input_path)
    df_data = get_S3_csv_data(spath_list[0])
    header_ = get_header_names(df_data)

    sp = read_json(json_path, header_)


    result_spec = None
    result_json = None

    if user_specific_geo:
        # result_spec, result_json, result_json_const  = main_pipeline_user_specific_copy(spec, files, input_path, files_geo, dependent_variable, variable_name, trans_and_values)
        result_spec, result_json, result_json_const  = main_pipeline_user_specific(spec,store_path_list, files_geo, dependent_variable, variable_name, trans_and_values)
    else:  
       result_spec, result_json, result_json_const = main_pipeline(spec, dependent_variable,store_path_list)

    # payload_data = {"result_spec" : result_spec, "result_json" : result_json,
    #            "result_json_const" : result_json_const}

    return result_spec, result_json , result_json_const



if __name__ == "__main__":
    payload = get_params_api(request=None)
    result_spec,result_json_const, result_json = main_func(params=payload)
```

Answer (score 0):

The request object actually has no body attribute. To request data in json format without the help of the json package, you can use the [`get_json()`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/api/#flask.Request.get_json) function of the request object.

```
json_body = request.get_json()
```

Answer (score 0):

To access data passed to a POST request you can use any of below.

```
request.json.get('csv_path')
```

or

```
request.get_json('csv_path')  # as Detlef replied
```

requests object don't have body.

For /GET request you can use request.args.get('csv_path')

Also you can Optimize code by removing get_params_api() function and access necessary parameters in direct main_func() like upper example.

Comment: If you quote me, please do so correctly. `get_json()` can accept arguments, but not the key to query a value. The function returns a dict containing the data. `request.get_json()['csv_path']` or `request.get_json().get('csv_path')` would be the equivalent.

Comment: Please do not include text telling people to upvote answers.